# Endpoint tag order in web.config hosting WCF service in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

I host a WCF service in IIS and want to expose multiple endpoints (with different enpoint behaviours). The base address is determined by the IIS virtual directory and the .svc file name as I understand. I use the ***address*** attribute on the endpoints to distinguish them. For one endpoint I leave the address blank, because this is the default endpoint that is already in use by applications. On the other endpoint I set an address.

**Is it possible that the order of *endpoint* tags in the config file does matter?**

For the first configuration always the endpoint with the blank address kicks in, no matter it is addressed from the client with /Test or not:

```
<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBindingCfg" contract="myContract" address="" behaviorConfiguration="myBehaviorCfg"  />          
<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBindingCfg" contract="myContract" address="Test" />
```

For the second configuration everything works fine:

```
<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBindingCfg" contract="myContract" address="Test" />
<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBindingCfg" contract="myContract" address="" behaviorConfiguration="myBehaviorCfg"  />
```

Comment: The only way it would matter is if the endpoint elements were referenced via an indexer (I've seen that done before).  In your case, it sounds like that's not what you're doing, so I would not expect the order to matter.

Comment: I dont't reference the endpoints at all, the whole thing is handled by IIS / WCF.
By the way I am using Windows 10 build 10041 and Visual Studio 2015 RC. Maybe that is the problem, I am going to test the behavior on other OS / Devenv to see what happens.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue exists on Windows7 / VS2013